# How to verify checkbox is checked or unchecked in protractor when there is no property like isChecked OR isSelected?

Tags: angular, protractor

```
1). Unchecked Checkbox
<div _ngcontent-c10="" class="col-lg-4 ng-star-inserted">
    <label _ngcontent-c10="" class="checkbox-title label-text">
     <input _ngcontent-c10="" name="countryData" type="checkbox" id="cntryUNITED ARAB EMIRATES" value="UNITED ARAB EMIRATES">UNITED ARAB EMIRATES
     <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="checkmark"></div>
     </label>
</div>

2). Checked Checkbox
<div _ngcontent-c10="" class="col-lg-4 ng-star-inserted">
    <label _ngcontent-c10="" class="checkbox-title label-text">
     <input _ngcontent-c10="" name="countryData" type="checkbox" id="cntryARMENIA" value="ARMENIA">ARMENIA
     <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="checkmark"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

I am using protractor tool. How to identify or which property to use to verify checkbox is checked or unchecked, as there is no such specific property is defined.

Comment: Asign a boolean to a variable and check for the variable is she's **true** or **false**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the isSelected() property to check it.

[image]

refer this https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected

Comment: Welcome Rajesh.